# Переход на заранее не определённый url в Django

Tags: python, django

Раньше я пользовался Flask, и там был такой вариант это сделать:

```
@app.route("/<name:type>")
def main(name):
    pass
```

Подскажите, как то же самое можно сделать в Djnago?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если правильно понял фразу "заранее не определенный" то также:

`views.py`:

```py
def main(request, name):
    pass
```

`urls.py`:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('main/<str:name>/', views.main),
]
```

[Подробнее в документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/)